# React type checking using flow failing for this.props.history.push

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I am doing type checking using flow in React.
I am getting error for below scenario,
how to handle this.props.history.push('/home') 
How can I define It in props? 
I have tried like below but Its not working ,

```
type Prop = { onLoginSuccess: function, setContextDetails: function, callErrorLogger: function, history:string, push:string }; 
type State = { username: string, password: string, loginsuccess: bool, isLoading: bool }; 
class Login extends React.Component<Prop, State> {
// here I have some code
this.props.history.push('/home') ;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I cleaned up some of your code and types to be more correct against flow syntax. But this should work.

You basically define your `history` type the same way as you would a normal object and your `push` function can be declared with either `Function` or to be more strict using arrow function syntax which I've used below.

```
type Prop = {
  onLoginSuccess: Function,
  setContextDetails: Function,
  callErrorLogger: Function,
  history: {
    push: (string) => void,
  },
};

type State = {
  username: string,
  password: string,
  loginsuccess: boolean,
  isLoading: boolean,
};

class Login extends React.Component<Prop, State> {
  // here I have some code
  onClick() {
    this.props.history.push('/home');
  }
}
```

Here's a try-flow for you to see the typings in action.
https://flow.org/try/#0JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQdMAnmFnAArFhwC8cA3nThwIAOwAyEAObBRAZQCuuXFlSoAXHABiC0fmBiANELiosMAMJiYWAB4wAIueTAANhu279Rk7mSvXAFEoYihJKSksKE0dPRgDUWNhAAtgVBhoJk1BYWEwBVRkzQAKdKhZKQBKXgA+OAA3CGAAEyS4AF9jdvpGFjY5GGQbXgETAqjRZBAsTTKKtrA0VAB3aGbZmHLRKTbXaVlUJRU1TQAjCAhXHESTNMlkZoqzi6vkG+6hOlxXJbhw2Tgdhsoma6GweBgADorOAxFhRDAADycCBgQxwAZDLB1HJwAD0eLgySibAAkkTkPU2KgSGxcBBmlgTGILK5gLgANbFaq44QwVKoSFgLiCgUZKBMIUFZLFMh45K0siVejCdp0dpwIA

I also recommend in the future you tag your post to `flowtype` which should get your more help.